# Create Application Folder and load data in it xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to create the Folder in Xamarin iOS Application and save Image to that Folder.
I am using following Code to create the folder

```
ALAssetsLibrary library = new ALAssetsLibrary();
                library.AddAssetsGroupAlbum("RentBlazr", g => 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Folder Created");
                    //originalImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) => { });
                }, 
                error => 
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("Error:" + error);
                });
```

By this Folder is successfully created in Albums Folder..But I am unable to save the Image captured by device Camera to this recently created Folder.

Answer (score 1):

I use the PCLStorage Package for this. It's free, and you can install it from the NugetGallery.
https://github.com/dsplaisted/pclstorage

It have simple API to work with file system.

```
public async Task PCLStorageSample()
{
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("answer.txt",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await file.WriteAllTextAsync("42");
}
```